# How can I put a js variable into jstl as key to find into hashmap?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, el

I need to pass the key with a js var but I don't know the way to use it in c:out tag. My code is:

```js
station = stationInfo[i][1];
var stationsLines = <c:out value="${lineas[${station}]}"></c:out>;
```

station into c:out is the key that I want to find. If I put the Key manually the code works correctly, but using the js variable the c:out does not work.
I need help please.

Comment: station is misspelled here `${lineas[${sation}]}`

Comment: Also have you tried removing the ${ } around station? so it is just `${lineas[station]}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using javascript variable inside jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307445/using-javascript-variable-inside-jstl)

Comment: When i put ${lineas[station]} jstl takes station as the key so does not return any value... the problem is that I don´t know how to integrate this js variable to find into the hashmap with the jstl tags...

Comment: I had tried too with + to to concatenate "${lineas["+station+"]}"

Comment: You cannot use Javascript in EL. Javascript is evaluated at client side after the EL was evaluated at the server side. You need to Ajax this somehow.