# Using JavaScript variable in JSTL / JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I need to do a validation to see if I should show one thing or another in my JSP. I tried doing this validation in JavaScript because I don't want to make a huge if statement in the jsp:

```
var canEdit = false;
var varA = <=% JavaClass.A =%>
var varB = <=% JavaClass.B =%>
if (varA == document.myForm.paramA && varB == document.myForm.paramB) 
{
  canEdit = true;
}
```

And I need to do something like the following:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${canEdit}">
    ...do something
   </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    ... do another thing
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

However it seems like the JSP isn't able to find that variable (I also tried with "param.canEdit", request.getParameter("canEdit")), so instead I tried using  tag with the scriptlet so I can reference the enum in the JavaClass:

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="<%= JavaClass.A =%>"/>
```

But I get an error saying that TLD doesn't allow expressions in the value attribute, so I can't use that either.

So in the end I find myself doing something like this:

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${myForm.paramA eq 'A' && myForm.paramB eq 'B'}">
    ...do something
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
      ... do another thing
   </c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>
```

So obviously is very probably that it would go wrong the moment the value of JavaClass.A changes to another.

My last hope is to do the validation in Java and pass the canEdit variable as an attribute from the ActionForm (I am using Struts 1).

It is possible to pass a JavaScript variable to an JSTL validation?

Thanks.

Comment: possible dublicate of [using javascript variable in JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3307445/5813861)

Comment: You will need AJAX to send http request to the server with the JS variable